# IE8 registry location for multiple home page tabs

Tags: windows-registry, internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

I'd like to open three tabs when ever I open IE8. I've found where to define the start page, but how do I define the other two tabs?

Answer (score 3):

[Jared Harley](https://superuser.com/questions/151536/ie8-registry-location-for-multiple-home-page-tabs/151539#151539) is corect. If you want to do that using Registry Editor then go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main`

Here `Start Page`(String value) value is for main home page. Set main home page here. And `Secondary Start Pages`(Multi-string value) value is for other home pages. Write home pages in different line here.

Comment: See here for how to add multi string values for the Secondary Start Pages http://stackoverflow.com/a/23569945/74585

Answer (score 1):

In the Internet Explorer settings window, under the "General" tab, type in each webpage you want to open on its own line and click OK.

[image: settings window]

Comment: Alternatively, open the tabs you want, then go to Tools, Internet Options and click "Use current".